# How to I setup a folder to pass files on without holding them?

Tags: sync, ftp, dropbox

Is it possible to create a folder where Whenever a file is placed in it, the file is automatically copied to another specified location and then the original file is deleted?

What I'm trying to do is use drop box as an automatic file transferring service, but I don't need to the files to remain in drop box, they are being moved to a permanent storage device.

Before telling me to just FTP, don't... The Dropbox transfer process is my only option. The files being output from the server can't be sent via ftp for several reasons, but can be automatically added to a dropbox folder. Just take my word for it.

So what I want it to do is on another local machine as soon as a file arrives in the dropbox folder, its moved to the local machine and then deleted from the dropbox folder.

Is this possible to setup or is there a program capable of automating this?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish, or why you are trying to do it. The whole "Before telling me to just FTP, don't... Just take my word for it" part does not provide a lot of insight to give you the best solution for it with other technologies. Maybe clarify the environment, and why one way is not a good way to do something, before asking about other ways to do it.

Comment: The file source is a video game server. The files are backups of game data. The sever files can't be loaded to an ftp server without coding a whole new plugin to do it. A simple plugin that copies the files to a dropbox folder already exists and works perfectly. The way I have to do it at the moment is to manually copy the files from the drop box folder into a local unshared folder and then delete the dropbox folders before the next auto upload. I simply wish to automate this.

Comment: Okay, that is a bit more useful - so what O/S are you using, and what are you familiar with in terms of scripting?

Comment: Windows server 2012. Pretty good with simple scripts and batches, etc. was hoping there was a more simple solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a batch script with Task Scheduler to move the files for you. A rude example is as follows:

```
dir foo
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 9289-2974

 Directory of C:\tmp\foo

03/18/2013  10:35 PM    <DIR>          .
03/18/2013  10:35 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/18/2013  10:35 PM                 0 fileA.txt
03/18/2013  10:35 PM                 0 fileB.txt
               2 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  100,050,911,232 bytes free


set backupDate=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~7,2%
mkdir %backupDate%

copy foo %backupDate%

rmdir /S /Q foo
```

With foo being your directory inside DropBox.